# php Shuffle multi-dimensional array whilst maintaining column order

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
$lee[] = array("question" => "3", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "4", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "5", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "6", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "7", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "8", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "9", "appeared" => "2");
$lee[] = array("question" => "10", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "12", "appeared" => "3");
$lee[] = array("question" => "15", "appeared" => "3");
$lee[] = array("question" => "19", "appeared" => "3");


function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}

array_sort_by_column($lee, 'appeared');
```

So far so good - now my array is sorted by the 'appeared' column in ascending order.

Now comes the problem. I want to randomly shuffle the array, **but still maintaining the "appeared" column in ascending order**

How can this be done? I have no clue..

Comment: You want to shuffle 'parts' of array. So divide array in parts, shuffle each part and merge'em

Comment: So you want to shuffle the "question" part of the array but keep the appeared order as is? A short example of what you have tried and a minimal example of how the end result should look like would be nice.

Comment: The function "array_sort_by_column" sorts the array by column "appeared" into ascending order... I want to be able to randomly shuffle the array but still keep the appeared column in ascending order.

Comment: You should have to create 2 different arrays.

Comment: Can someone give me an example as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lee[] = array("question" => "3", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "4", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "5", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "6", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "7", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "8", "appeared" => "1");
$lee[] = array("question" => "9", "appeared" => "2");
$lee[] = array("question" => "10", "appeared" => "0");
$lee[] = array("question" => "12", "appeared" => "3");
$lee[] = array("question" => "15", "appeared" => "3");
$lee[] = array("question" => "19", "appeared" => "3");

$parts = [];
// Group items by `appeared` value
foreach ($lee as $item) {
    $parts[$item['appeared']][] = $item;
}

// shuffle each group
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    shuffle($part);
}

// sort array by keys in ascending order
ksort($parts);
// merge groups to one array
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $parts));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that these other answers are over-engineered (no wonder you can't follow what they do).  You only need two function calls, `shuffle()` then `usort()`.  There is no need to group them at all.  (I'm going use the "spaceship" operator in my demo, but you can use any of the old-school comparison techniques if your php version requires it.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1845f757bf2960d8ad51d1801a8db94bb3cbc9c7))

```
shuffle($lee);  // shuffle the array
usort($lee,function($a,$b){return $a['appeared']<=>$b['appeared'];});  // sort shuffled array by appeared value
var_export($lee);
```

Possible Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'question' => '10',
    'appeared' => '0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'question' => '5',
    'appeared' => '0',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'question' => '6',
    'appeared' => '0',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'question' => '3',
    'appeared' => '0',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'question' => '4',
    'appeared' => '1',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'question' => '8',
    'appeared' => '1',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'question' => '7',
    'appeared' => '1',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'question' => '9',
    'appeared' => '2',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'question' => '12',
    'appeared' => '3',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'question' => '15',
    'appeared' => '3',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'question' => '19',
    'appeared' => '3',
  ),
)
```

p.s. Ordering by `appeared` DESC is as simple as swapping `$a` and `$b` after `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $lee[] = array("question" => "3", "appeared" => "0");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "4", "appeared" => "1");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "5", "appeared" => "0");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "6", "appeared" => "0");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "7", "appeared" => "1");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "8", "appeared" => "1");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "9", "appeared" => "2");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "10", "appeared" => "0");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "12", "appeared" => "3");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "15", "appeared" => "3");
    $lee[] = array("question" => "19", "appeared" => "3");

    function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
        $sort_col = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
            $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
        }

        array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
    }
    array_sort_by_column($lee, 'appeared');
    foreach( $lee as $row){
        $question[] = $row['question'];
    }
    shuffle($question);

    for($i=0;$i<count($lee);$i++){
        $lee[$i]['question'] = $question[$i];
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($lee);
```